# Which algorithm to optimize this problem?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I do need to find coefficients of a parametric model given observations, and I was wondering which algorithm I should use. The problem is as follows.

I have a set of values $\mathbf x_i = (x_{i,1},\dots,x_{i,d}) \in \Delta_d$ where $\Delta_d$ is the unit simplex (each $x_{i,j}$ is positive and $\lvert \mathbf x_i \rvert \le 1$), and corresponding observation for the response $y_i$, in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$. I want to fit the following model:

$$y(\mathbf x) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_j \ln\left( 1 + \langle \mathbf b_j, \mathbf x \rangle\right)$$

Where the parameters are:

- $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $b_{1,1},\dots,b_{n,d}$ are all positive reals
- $n$ is a given integer, a bigger $n$ gives a more flexible function.

This function seems to be convex in its parameters (well, I'm not sure), but the number of parameters is huge (my typical use case is $n = 100, d = 2 \text{ or } 3$ with $m = 10000$ observations).

What kind of algorithm do you think might work on this problem? Do you think it could be practical to recurse on $n$ (fit one more $(a_j,\mathbf b_j)$ pair, remove $a_j \ln\left( 1 + \langle \mathbf b_j, \mathbf x_i \rangle\right)$ from each $y_i$ and start over)?

Edit: If this kind of model already exists in the literature, could you tell me where to find documentations?

Comment: Have you tried the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm?